# How to create multiple instances of a custom data structure in Linux 64-bit Asm?

Tags: oop, assembly, data-structures, queue, x86-64

I am using Linux x86-64 Assembly Language with the NASM assembler and Intel syntax.

I have written a functional, primitive single-ended queue that is implemented as an array of bytes like so:

```
queue_size equ 1000
queue dq queue_size dup(0)
```

And merely prompting the user to input which operation they wish to perform, which value they wish to perform it on and modifying the array in accordance to how queues work.

Is there any way to use an OOP approach and place the queue in something like a class so that I create multiple instances of it simultaneously?

I tried encapsulating it in a label like so:

```
_queue:
    ;queue here
```

And calling it when needed but this way I can only have one queue at a time.

I understand that OOP is a high-level abstraction, how can I implement it on a low-level such that I can have several queues at once without repeating my code?

Comment: As I commented on [your previous version of this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77283736/224132), this doesn't require OOP stuff like polymorphism, just basic code-reuse by having your functions take a pointer arg (to a struct, or a pointer+size) instead of using global variables.  Same as you'd do in a simple non-OOP language like C.  (Like C++ without `virtual`, calling a method on an object just passes the object address as the first arg, to a normal function that isn't special at the asm level vs. if you'd written it as a non-member function; the implicit `this` arg is just syntactic sugar)